# Probability - a clerk controlling customers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> It is known that a certain clerk checks on 15 out of 100 customers.
>   What is the probability that from a group of 12 customers, exactly 3 will be
>   checked on?

I haven't got a faintest idea how to solve this task - could you give me any suggestions? I tried drawing a "tree", but it wasn't too effective.

Comment: Not sure what "controls" means in this context, or if that's even relevant.  Are you just saying there are $15$ special customers out of $100$, you draw $12$ at random (without replacement)...what is the probability that at least $3$ are special?  (note:  you might mean "exactly three".  You should clarify).

Comment: It means that he checks on them. <br>
The task is about exactly three special customers.

Comment: Ok.  In that case, Hint:  how many ways are there to chose $12$ out of $100$ with no restrictions?  How many ways are there to choose $3$ controlled clients out of $15$?  How many ways are there to choose $9$ out of the uncontrolled $85$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to select exactly 3 persons from the lot of 15 people who are being controlled by the clerk and the rest of 9 from the other 85 customers. Thus the probability is
$$\frac{{15 \choose 3}{85 \choose 9}}{{100 \choose 12}}$$
The denominator shows all the possible ways of selecting 12 persons from a group of 100 people.